# Start a systemd service after a device has been mounted

Tags: raid, mount, systemd

I'm writing a systemd's .service file for minidlnad (DLNA server) under CentOS 7. Since my media file collection is hosted on a RAID array, I need that array to be mounted BEFORE the minidlnad server is started. Both the RAID array and minidlnad should be started on boot. Is there a way to do this in systemd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adjust dependencies in your .service's `Unit` section:

On centos:

```
Requires=mdmonitor.service local-fs.target
After=mdmonitor.service local-fs.target
```

On other distrib, it could be:

```
Requires=mdadm.service local-fs.target
After=mdadm.service local-fs.target
```

The raid service file should execute `/sbin/mdadm --monitor --scan`

source:http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Comment: Is this enough to be sure that the raid device is also mounted (as specified in /etc/fstab) and not just assembled?

Comment: edited to be sure that `local-fs.target` is already activated

Comment: Apparently I don't have a mdadm.service file in /usr/lib/systemd/system, just mdadm-last-resort@.service, mdadm-grow-continue@.service and mdadm-last-resort@.timer. Should I still put the mdadm.service entry in requires and after?

Comment: Sorry don't have a centos installed to try, but it seems that you may have a  `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mdmonitor.service` which is the one you should use, i'll edit my answer

Comment: Yes, I have mdmonitor.service and it does execute that command. Thank you very much!

Comment: It should be noted that although this is the selected answer, this is not the preferred `systemd` way of achieving the objective. For an easier and more robust solution, see [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/998109/360870).

Answer (score 11):

`systemd` has a specific directive for this case, called `RequiredMountsFor`; see `man systemd.directives`.

The usage would be `RequiresMountsFor=[mountpoint]`, e.g. `RequiresMountsFor=/var`.

Comment: I'd disagree with your comment above that "this is not the preferred systemd way". `RequiresMountsFor=` is  ignored if the mount point is marked `noauto`, so sometimes the explicit `Requires` target is not only recommended but required.

Comment: @Auspex The OP clearly stated that the question relates to system boot. In this regard, the title of the Q may be seen as incomplete, while my answer addressed this scenario. Do you see a case where a `noauto` option would be used during boot?

Comment: I don't think it's relevant whether "noauto" would be used during boot. You argued with the accepted answer because you claimed it was not the preferred systemd way. I see nothing in the documentation to say that, and reasons why you might want to avoid your method.

Comment: @Auspex I also don't think it's relevant _when_ `noauto` is used. It's just that the OP's use case suggests that he's not going to use `noauto`. That's got nothing to do with the documentation, but rather with the scenario of the question.